# How do I calculate a fee percentage to a transaction upon submit to Paypal?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to calculate a fee on an amount that users want to pay via paypal.  If they want to donate $20 I need to be able to calculate 2.9% fee so that when the user clicks the donate button to launch paypal they can see the amount with the fee included. I haven't been able to figure it out reading the various questions/answers.  Here is the code for the button.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  After clicking save it doesn't look like the code is being displayed.  It's html code so that's what I'm looking for, the code to calculate the fee percentage.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

(donation amount * fee percentage) / 100

This will give the fee amount based on the percentage. That'll be...

($20 * 2.9) / 100 = $0.58